# Core Bluetooth receives data from Peripheral in Background Mode continuously for more than 80 hours

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process, core-bluetooth, rxbluetooth

I am working on an healthcare product for in hand experience to receive ECG Data with the help ECG Detection BLE Peripheral and iOS App.

This app will be installed on the patient iPhone/iPad and patient will have a BLE accessory and which will send ECG Data to the mobile app and patient can take an ECG Test for 72hours even, in this case I cannot force a patient to be only with this app in foreground for all 72 hours. Hence I moved the data receiving part from the BLE accessory to background. Hence the app will receive the ECG Data from the BLE Peripheral even in the background. But when the user using some other heavy resource required app, then iOS stops the background operation for receiving the ECG Data. Kindly help me to resolve this. Do we have anything like Service in Android which will run the process continuously even when the app not alive or when the app goes to background OS will never stops the operation.

Comment: Have you adopted Core Bluetooth state restoration? It should work for you as long as the peripheral is using indicate/notify for new data. However, you can't really rely on iOS to perform continuous background Bluetooth transfer. I would have thought a more reliable approach would be for the device to store the data on-board and transfer it to the iOS app after recording was complete. That will also handle the case where the phone isn't in range of the peripheral, goes flat etc.

Comment: I have not done this before, but still when app launch, I know the UDID which I get previously when connected, keeping that UDID again I am establishing connection and it works fine. Thanks for the update on state restoration I will look into this. I need to know when I add UIBackgroundModes with bluetooth-central and bluetooth-peripheral in info-plist, Will OS launch the app in background?. However when memory require warning comes I believe OS will definitely release the the background app and will it retry to launch in background again when memory becomes free?

Comment: That is why you need to state restoration. That ensures that iOS relaunched your app when there is Bluetooth activity